# Add the contents of 2 Mats to another Mat opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I just want to add the contents of 2 different `Mat`s to 1 other `Mat`. I tried:

```
Mat1.copyTo(newMat);
Mat2.copyTo(newMat);
```

But that just seemed to overwrite the previous contents of the `Mat`.

This may be a simple question, but I'm lost.

Comment: Try `newMat = Mat1+Mat2;`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It depends on what you want to *add*. For example, you have two 3x3 Mat:

```
cv::Mat matA(3, 3, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(20));
cv::Mat matB(3, 3, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(80));
```

You can add `matA` and `matB` to a new 3x3 Mat with value 100 using [matrix operation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions):

```
auto matC = matA + matB;
```

Or using array operation [cv::add](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add) that does the same job:

```
cv::Mat matD;
cv::add(matA, matB, matD);
```

Or even [mixing](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html#adding-images) two images using [cv::addWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted):

```
cv::Mat matE;
cv::addWeighted(matA, 1.0, matB, 1.0, 0.0, matE);
```

Sometimes you need to merge two Mat, for example create a 3x6 Mat using [cv::Mat::push_back](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back):

```
cv::Mat matF;
matF.push_back(matA);
matF.push_back(matB);
```

Even merge into a two-channel 3x3 Mat using [cv::merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge):

```
auto channels = std::vector<cv::Mat>{matA, matB};
cv::Mat matG;
cv::merge(channels, matG);
```

Think about what you want to add and choose a proper function.

Answer (score 7):

You can use push_back():

```
newMat.push_back(Mat1);
newMat.push_back(Mat2);
```