# omp reduction on vector of cv::Mat or cv::Mat in general

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

```
//In other words, this equilavent to cv::Mat1f mat(5,n)
//i.e. a matrix 5xn
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat(5,cv::Mat1f::zeros(1,n));
std::vector<float> indexes(m);
// fill indexes
// m >> nThreads (from hundreds to thousands)
for(size_t i=0; i<m; i++){
  mat[indexes[m]] += 1;
}
```

The expected result is to increase each element of each row by one. This is a toy example, the actual sum is far more compliacted. I tried to parallelize it with:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(vec_float_plus : std::vector<cv::Mat1f> : \
            std::transform(omp_out.begin(), omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_out.begin(), std::plus<cv::Mat1f>())) \
            initializer(omp_priv=omp_orig);

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(vec_float_plus : mat)
for(size_t i=0; i<m; i++){
    mat[indexes[m]] += 1;
}
```

But this fails because each element of each row is randomly inizitialized. How can I solve this?

So I found out that the problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202651/4480180). So I should initialize `mat` with:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat(5);
for(size_t i=0; i<mat.size(); i++)
  mat[i] = cv::Mat1f::zeros(1,n);
```

But then this would create problems with `omp_priv = omp_orig`, since it would consider `std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat(5);` and it's values are undefined. How can I solve this? The only solution that came to my mind is to create a wrapper structure, something like:

```
class vectMat{
public:
    vectMat(size_t rows, size_t j){
        for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
            mats.push_back(cv::Mat1f::zeros(1,j));
    }
private:
    std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mats;
};
```

But then what should I implement to make it work with the rest of the code?

Comment: What do you mean with *"each element of each row is randomly inizitialized"*?

Comment: @Zulan In the previous case the different lines were "linked", so I can't initialize `mat` as in the first case, but then there are problems with `omp_priv = omp_orig` , don't you think?

Comment: @Zulan Please give a look at my upadted question

Answer (score 1):

Types such as `cv::Mat1f`, that use references instead of copying, are indeed dangerous in this context. You make a clear explicit solution by splitting the `parallel` region and the `for` loop.

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(vec_mat1f_plus : std::vector<cv::Mat1f> : \
            std::transform(omp_out.begin(), omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_out.begin(), std::plus<cv::Mat1f>()));
// initializer not necessary if you initialize explicitly

std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat;
#pragma omp parallel reduction(vec_mat1f_plus : mat)
{
  mat = std::vector<cv::Mat1f>(5);
  for (auto& elem : mat) {
    elem = cv:Mat1f::zeros(1, n);
  }
  #pragma omp for
  for(size_t i=0; i<m; i++){
    mat[indexes[m]] += 1;
  }
}
```

<sup>I haven't tested whether `std::plus<cv::Mat1f>` works, but it [looks good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590031/add-the-contents-of-2-mats-to-another-mat-opencv-c).</sup>

Your approach with `vectMat` will also work if you provide an `operator=` that deep-copies the underlying `Mat` with `clone()`, and keep the initializer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I oversimplified my example, please look at my updated question

Comment: @justHelloWorld I updated the answer on your updated question. Think I got it not what you need.

Comment: thanks for your update. However, at the end of this code `mat.size()=0` :(

Comment: Of course if was 0: I was not initializing `mat` before the reduction (so stupid for me). I edited your question (first time that I do it, I don't know how it works :D)