# Vector of cv::Mat are linked between them

Tags: opencv, vector, mat

```
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat = std::vector<cv::Mat1f>(10,cv::Mat1f::zeros(1,10));
mat[0]+=1;
for(size_t i=0;i<mat.size();i++)
    std::cout<<mat[i]<<std::endl;
```

And it prints:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

How can I avoid this? It would be very important that the vector initialization is inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The `vector` constructor uses the `Mat` copy constructor, which only copies the header but not the data. You need to explicitly use `clone()` somehow, or create a new matrix every time: E.g:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat(10);
for (size_t i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++) {
    mat[i] = cv::Mat1f(1, 10, 0.f);
}
```

or:

```
cv::Mat1f m = cv::Mat1f(1, 10, 0.f);
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat(10);
for (size_t i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++) {
    mat[i] = m.clone();
}
```

or:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat(10);
std::generate(mat.begin(), mat.end(), []() {return cv::Mat1f(1, 10, 0.f); });
```

or:

```
cv::Mat1f m = cv::Mat1f(1, 10, 0.f);
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat(10);
std::generate(mat.begin(), mat.end(), [&m]() {return m.clone(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a pain. Does exist any row-by-row iterator? If not, how can I implement it?

Comment: What do you mean by "row by row" iterator?

Comment: I'm going to open another question for that, I think it's not a good  behavior for me :)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203590/cvmat1f-row-by-row-iterator) is the new question!