# cv::Mat1f row-by-row iterator

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat1f> mat;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    mat.push_back(cv::Mat1f::zeros(1,10));
//fill mat somehow
//sum mat row by row (in this case with itself)
std::transform(mat.begin(), mat.end(), mat.begin(), mat.begin(), std::plus<cv::Mat1f>());
```

Now, I would like to do the `std::transofrm(...)` stuff using `cv::Mat1f` instead of `std::vector<cv::Mat1f>`, but in order to do that I need a row-by-row iterator. How can I do this? Do I need to create a new class that inherits `cv::Mat1f` and define a new iterator?

Comment: I don't get why you need the vector... can't you just have a matrix with 10 rows?

Comment: Because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193566/omp-reduction-on-vector-of-cvmat-or-cvmat-in-general?noredirect=1#comment73475183_43193566). I'm trying to parallelize that code and `omp declare reduction` requires the `transofrm` which requires the "row-by-row" iterator.